# Get list of all values for a specific key in a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filtering, typeerror

I have this list with contents below:

```
quake_list = [{'time': '2016-01-12T21:05:59.000Z',
               'location': {'latitude': 60.5079, 'longitude': -142.9635},
               'event': {'magnitude': 1.3, 'depth': 9.1},
               'type': 'earthquake',
               'status': 'reviewed'},
              {'time': '2016-01-12T21:02:24.760Z',
               'location': {'latitude': 38.7978325, 'longitude': -122.7196655},
               'event': {'magnitude': 1.0, 'depth': -0.77},
               'type': 'earthquake',
               'status': 'automatic'},
               ...]
```

Another thing, I need to filter out the None entries
It seems, the file has none entries for this value.

That's why I get the error message

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I need to create a list named magnitude with all values for this:

`magnitude = [1.3,1.0]`

Comment: This reads as a blog post, did you have a question? [ask]

Comment: Please make sure you have your code attached to your post. This is not how SO works (please make it clean).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> [d['event']['magnitude'] for d in quake_list]
[1.3, 1.0]
```

To only record magnitudes if the record is an earthquake, use:

```
>>> [d['event']['magnitude'] for d in quake_list if d['type'] == 'earthquake']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mag_list = [quake['event']['magnitude'] for quake in quake_list]
print(mag_list)
```